# how can I set my gradient background in css for full width and height of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I just downloaded example page from `bootstrap`, taken from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/)

it is designed so that there are no scrollbars and the whole content is one-page only.

Now, I also found the example with dynamic gradient changer [here](https://codepen.io/quasimondo/pen/lDdrF)

I want to use the gradient changer on the bootstrap cover page.

The bootstrap cover page has css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and the gradient-changer has:

```
body{
   background-color: #000000;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }

#gradient
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

as you can see the '#gradient' has `height: 800px`, so it does not cover the page vertically in 100%. How can I modify this code so that the height covers 100%?

Comment: dude add your code to snippet, so that it is easy to solve

Comment: Check this [*`Codepen`*](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/bwNWNo), it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

Wrap the template code inside a `div` (I give it the ID `#gradient`), then set `width` and `height` for it. Other things are the same as on CodePen and Bootstrap Cover template.

```
#gradient {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```js
var colors = new Array(
  [62,35,255],
  [60,255,60],
  [255,35,98],
  [45,175,230],
  [255,0,255],
  [255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient()
{
  
  if ( $===undefined ) return;
  
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

 $('#gradient').css({
   background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
  
  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
    
    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    
  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
/*
* Globals
*/

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
* Base structure
*/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
* Header
*/
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
* Cover
*/

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
* Footer
*/

.mastfoot {
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
* Affix and center
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}


#gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="gradient">

  <div class="site-wrapper">

    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

      <div class="cover-container">

        <div class="masthead clearfix">
          <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inner cover">
          <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
          <p class="lead">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="mastfoot">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found is to use a div and style this as shown below:

```
#div{
    background: #colour;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #colour, #colour);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #colour, #colour);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #colour, #colour);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #colour, #colour);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

VW refers to viewport width, WH to viewport height and 1vw = 1% of viewport width, 1vh = 1% of viewport height.

Let me know if this works for you, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

please try this, as per your requirement.

```
body, html {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#gradient {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/ujfar6t9/16/)

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery function will make height 100% of the screen that loads the page, so it's responsive and work with all browsers too:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var wheight = $(window).height();
    $('#gradient').css("min-height", wheight);
});
</script>
```